# How do I upgrade my Marionette js app from 1.x to 2.x?

Tags: python, upgrade, marionette

It looks like there was a pretty massive shift from 1.x to 2.x.  My app doesn't work anymore.  No errors.  Just doesn't work.  I'm 1.8.3 trying to get to 2.4.1 to take advantage of the new collection optimizations.

I see there is a tool to help with the upgrade:

[Marionette Upgrade](https://github.com/marionettejs/Marionette.Upgrade)

But it requires Python knowledge to run it.  I know nothing about Python.  The instructions for running look pretty foreign to me.  I did install the latest version of Python on my Windows 7 machine but I'm just not understanding the instructions on running the tool.

Is this the only approach to upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest "issue" is probably the "start" event. Before, you would listen for the "initialize:after" event to do stuff when the app starts, but that event has been renamed "start".

Also, make sure to read through https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fuXb9N5LwmdPn-teMwAo3c8JTx6ifUowbqFY1NNSdp8/edit# : you'll probably recognize bits of your code that need to be updated.

Comment: Hmmm...  This is not good.  Just not a good position to be in.  There's quite a bit of code.  And no errors.  Just nothing to latch onto to guide the process.

Comment: Are you able to confirm your app actually gets started?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually run all the search and replaces the tool does by starting here:

https://github.com/marionettejs/Marionette.Upgrade/blob/master/upgrade.py#L108

left side strings are old,  right side new.